# Central Logging Service across Line-of-Business applications

Tags: architecture, logging

We have an Enterprise with various technologies: Web clients, Windows clients, .Net Services, Java Services, Cobol....

Most communication between systems is via web services. We have a standard which includes a corelation id in the header of the web service calls, which allows us to trace a request across systems.

What we would like to do is to have one place where we could go and check what has gone wrong and where did it get stuck. Our problem currently is that we have to check the log files of the individual systems.

Could anyone suggest a product or an implementation pattern to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) does an awesome job. But it's not free.

Answer (score 3):

The implementation pattern is centralized logging. Using a tool such as logstash, scribe, [nxlog](http://nxlog.org) (note: I'm affiliated with this project) you can collect the logs at a central server where you can then analyze your data (with elasticsearch, graylog2, splunk, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Checkout Graylog2: http://graylog2.org/

> Manage your logs in the dark and have lasers going and make it look
>   like you're from space.

It's the best (central) log mamnagement tool I've seen so far. Graylog is build to centralize syslog messages, but can also be feeded with log messages within your application send in AMQP.

There are libraries for PHP, Perl, Ruby, Python, node.js, .NET. Not sure, if there is a suitable library for you, but I bet you can implement Graylog pretty easy using the standard message protocols.